# Regex to count hyphenated and apostrophe words

Tags: regex, string

How can I modify this regex to count words that include hyphen or apostrophe as one word?

```
@"^(\w+\b.*?){numOfWords}"
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I am trying to get this expression to return the first n words, while counting words with a ' or hyphen as one word

```
string substringWords = Regex.Match(stringWords, @"^(\w+\b.*?){" +      numberOfWords + "}").ToString();
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed question

Answer (score 0):

`((?:\w+(?:(?:[-']\w+)+|\b)(?:\s+|$)){3})` matches the first 3 words that include any number of hyphens as one match.
They can also be separated by any number of white space elements.

Comment: Thank you. Can this be edited to match the first N words matching the regex criteria. That's what I had included the {numOfWords} for

Comment: Updated my answer, does this help?

Comment: It seems to be throwing an exception..                                                                       +  Regex.Match(stringWords, @"((?:\w+(?:(?:[-']\w+)+|\b)(?:\s+|$)){4}").ToString() 'Regex.Match(stringWords, @"((?:\w+(?:(?:[-']\w+)+|\b)(?:\s+|$)){4}").ToString()' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' string {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: What language are you using? [Online](https://regex101.com/r/bU3lP6/1) it works fine using all flavors.

Answer (score 0):

For a string like:

> look at the new student o'brien, he's from peter's class

The regex from Vignesh Kumar will recognize `o'brien` correctly as a word, but also `he's` and `peter's`

In this case, I think o'brien should be one word and the apostrophe in `he's` and `peter's` should be removed.

I think this might get resolved by using a pre-defined set to indicate the exception

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around because I had the same problem for the Italian language, where the apostrophe can have a different function, dependning of its position, since can be (of course) an apostrophe between two words, the first ending and the second beginning with a vocal, but also can truncate an initial vocal (elision) or a final sillable of a word (apocopation). So, for instance, a text like

> perch'io 'l giorno e l'ora ch'i vidi 'l tuo core un po' triste

(because the day and the hour in which I saw  your heart a bit sad) contains:

```
perch'io -> perch[é] io (because I) (apostrophe)
'l giorno -> [i]l giorno (and the day) (elision)
e l'ora -> e l[a] ora (and the hour) (apostrophe)
ch'i' vidi -> ch[e] i[o] vidi (in which I saw) (apostrophe and elision together)
'l tuo core -> [i]l tuo cuore (elision)
un po' -> un po[co] (apocopation)
```

The solution I suggest, in this case, is a bit different:

```
['][a-zA-Z]+|[\S]+['](?=[a-zA-Z]+)|\b\w+[']?
```

or better:

```
['][a-zA-Zàòèéìù]+|[\S]+['](?=[a-zA-Zàòéèìù]+)|[a-zA-Zàòèìéù]+[']?
```

if we consider the accented letters.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RdpA2i/8)